# VLC fullscreen on Windows 10 erratic screensaver behavior

Tags: windows-10, vlc-media-player

So, I've had VLC on my Windows 10 Pro for years, and have noticed an erratic issue with the screensaver that I've yet to find a permanent solution to. I've tried other answers like [Screensaver interrupts video playback](https://superuser.com/questions/179363/screensaver-interrupts-video-playback) but it doesn't fix the issue. I'm curious if it has anything to do with the media I'm playing, which is typically either an .iso movie file, an .iso ripped DVD file, or .m4v, .mkv, or mp4 video files. The problems seem to happen most often with ripped DVD .iso files, though I can't fathom why.

The two problems that happen are:

1. The screensaver activates in VLC fullscreen video playback (playing).
2. The screensaver doesn't activate in VLC fullscreen after video playback (finished).

The screensaver for #1 activates in accordance with its Windows power time settings, after 10 minutes of no keyboard or mouse activity. The screensaver for #2 doesn't activate after this time period even though VLC has stopped playing.

My setting is already enabled for "Disable screensaver", which upon hover shows a pop-up saying "Disable the screensaver during video playback". There's no setting like "Allow the screensaver to run as normal when video has stopped playing". There's nothing mentioning fullscreen, oddly. I haven't tested it in non-fullscreen because I never use it that way without also using another app like a browser.

Typically the screensaver does not activate while video is playing fullscreen in VLC. I don't use any other video players so I don't know how those work. Typically the screensaver never activates after the video has stopped playing in VLC fullscreen. I can't explain this erratice behavior; I feel like I'm missing a special setting or tweak or quirk in VLC or Windows 10 Pro.

My Windows 10 Pro auto-updates and is on version 21H1. I keep my VLC version up to date when I'm prompted (every 2 weeks if an update is available), and it's at version 3.0.16 Vetinari.

[VLC > Tools > Preferences > Show Settings > All > Video > General Video Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E1Tff.png)

I'm not doing anything special in Windows Screensaver... and those settings while enabled never mattered anyway. My settings for over a year have been Screen saver Mystify, Wait 5 minutes, On resume display logon screen. There's no other settings I've set, and my Power Plan is default Balanced. I'm not sure what I can glean from there.

[Screen Saver Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/77XGU.png)

Comment: Which screensaver are you using?

Comment: Here is some background about how programs should work. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/power/system-sleep-criteria and https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-setthreadexecutionstate

Comment: @harrymc I added the screen saver settings to the question... though those have never mattered in relation to this while enabled. I don't see how that would affect VLC anyway, there's no option like "Override apps trying to override the screensaver". Care to share what you know about any of this, or any suggestions that you think should work? Please leave an answer if you've already dealt with this particular issue before or are very familiar with its inner workings. Note that I'm a little wary of following guesses down potentially irrelevant rabbit holes.

Comment: @user1292580 I'm not understanding what you're trying to tell me. Those links appear to be about programming an app for Windows, and I don't program VLC. How does this help resolve this situation?

Comment: If you're asking for my opinion, I say screensavers are screen-wasters, since all they do is waste electricity and shorten the life of the monitor, and also block the computer from true idle by engaging CPU & GPU. I usually set my computers to no screensaver, while in Advanced Power Options I set Display to "Turn off after" x minutes.